# How to select from table depend on value from another table column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make `sql` statement to `select` which `table` depend on value from some another `table` like this:

```
SELECT b.*, detail.*, t.date
FROM board AS b, transaction AS t,
 (CASE t.type
   WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT * FROM claim)
   WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT * FROM retrieve)
 END) AS detail
WHERE b.sn='D92AD006325' AND b.id=t.board_id AND detail.id=t.transaction_id
```

some part of tables look like this:

```
| board | |   transaction   | |   claim   | | retrieve |
|-------| |-----------------| |-----------| |----------|
| ...   | | board_id        | | id        | | id       |
|_______| | transaction_id  | | sender    | | code     |
          | type            | | location  | |__________|
          | date            | |___________|
          |_________________|
```

if `type = 0`, `transaction_id` means `claim.id`, else `retrieve.id`

so the outputs may be like:

```
| board.id | ... | claim.id | claim.sender | location  | retrieve.id | retrieve.code |       date       |
|----------|-----|----------|--------------|-----------|-------------|---------------|------------------|
| 19       | ... | 10       | SenderA      | locationA |             |               | 10/09/2015 18:09 |
| 19       | ... |          |              |           | 8           | 58/03165      | 14/09/2015 11:10 |
| 19       | ... | 14       | SenderB      | locationA |             |               | 20/09/2015 08:10 |
```

Comment: Does the output have the same number/type of columns or do the differ depending on the table?

Comment: Can you give the two queries you want as separate SQL commands as this will make the question more clearer.

Comment: So, the outputs are about the transactions of claiming and retrieving for each board

Answer (score 2):

Two simple joins and simple filter is much better than one complex join.

```
SELECT b.*, c.number, c.location, t.type, t.date
FROM board AS b, transaction AS t, claim AS c
WHERE b.sn='D92AD006325' AND b.id=t.board_id AND c.id=t.transaction_id AND t.type=0

UNION ALL

SELECT b.*, r.number, NULL AS location, t.type, t.date
FROM board AS b, transaction AS t, retrieve AS r
WHERE b.sn='D92AD006325' AND b.id=t.board_id AND r.id=t.transaction_id AND t.type=1
```

Alternative- join both tables with outer join, and use filter in the column:

```
SELECT b.*, 
       case when t.type = 0 then c.number else r.number end as number, 
       case when t.type = 0 then c.location else null end as location, 
       t.type,
       t.date
FROM board AS b
INNER JOIN transaction AS t,
   ON (b.id=t.board_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN claim c
   ON (c.id=t.transaction_id and t.type = 0)
LEFT OUTER JOIN retrieve r
   ON (r.id=t.transaction_id and t.type = 1)
WHERE b.sn='D92AD006325'
```

Comment: This is what I was aiming for too by asking for the two queries in the comments.

Comment: MySQL said: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns  because `claim` and `retrieve` have unmatched columns

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment using a dynamic SQL query.
This would make the SQL running logic simpler, readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I try to specify and name each column from both table to be matched and also replace a missing column in `retrieve` table with `NULL` like this:

```
SELECT b.*, c.number, c.location, t.type, t.date
FROM board AS b, transaction AS t, claim AS c
WHERE b.sn='D92AD006325' AND b.id=t.board_id AND c.id=t.transaction_id AND t.type=0

UNION ALL

SELECT b.*, r.number, NULL AS location, t.type, t.date
FROM board AS b, transaction AS t, retrieve AS r
WHERE b.sn='D92AD006325' AND b.id=t.board_id AND r.id=t.transaction_id AND t.type=1
```

that is work for me right now.

Any better ways?

Comment: Edited my answed - added null for missing column, and added alternative solution.